# MVC3: url with only controller and parameters (no action)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing, html.actionlink

im trying to create an Html.ActionLink with segments www.example.com/Store**/Segment1/Segment2/Segment3**. The segments are optional.

ive defined the following route:

```
routes.MapRoute("Store",
"{controller}/{Segment1}/{Segment2}/{Segment3}",  
new
{
controller = "Store",
action = "Show",
segment1 = UrlParameter.Optional,
segment2 = UrlParameter.Optional,
segment3 = UrlParameter.Optional
}
);
```

The Action should not be seen in the url. I cant seem to be able to create a valid link.

In the View i generate the links as follows:

```
<ul>
@foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in ViewBag.LinkList){<li>@Html.ActionLink(item.Key, "Show", "Store", new { item.Value })</li>}
</ul>
```

When i type the url in the adressbar everything goes well (the Action can read the segments as parameters), but i cant get the Html.ActionLink correct. 
Anyone can give me an example of a working ActionLink for this route? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You defined default for `segment2` twice, forgetting about `segment3` which breaks the whole thing because you didn't define segment variables in your `ActionLink` call.

Comment: thanks, edited that. it's a typo in the post though, the route in my code didnt have it :)

Comment: Oh, ok. `@Html.ActionLink(item.Key, "Show", "Store", new { item.Value })` this line looks wrong too, `new { item.Value }` is not valid expression.

Comment: i know, i need to create an actionlink that generates something like
~/Store/segment1/. 
item.Key is the urlname, and item.Value is the parameter

Comment: Like this `@Html.ActionLink(item.Key, "Show", "Store", new { segment1 = item.Value })`?

Comment: that generates a link like http://localhost:50107/Store/Segment1?Length=8 , instead of http://localhost:50107/Store/Segment1/. the different segments (deeper levels) should be generated dynamically..

Comment: What exactly item.Value contains? Corrected link from previous comment `@Html.ActionLink(item.Key, "Show", "Store", new { segment1 = item.Value }, null)`

Comment: item.Value can contain either "Segment1" or "Segment1/Segment2" or "Segment1/Segment2/Segment3". 
it should be 'pasted' at the end of the url like this:
localhost/Store/Segment1/Segment2